# Solvability of a group with order $p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ is a group whose order is $p^n$($p$ is prime), then $G$ is solvable.

How am I going to show this?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The center of such a group is non-trivial by the class formula.

Comment: See Rotman's or Rose's books, if you have an accesses to them.

Comment: Ironically the trigger that this post might get closed is exactly due to a good answer being added.

Comment: $p$-groups are nilpotent, hence solvable (see last answer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try by induction on the power of $p$. If $n=1$, $G$ is solvable by definition as a cyclic group of prime order.

Suppose that statement is true for all $k\leq n-1$. Suppose $|G|=p^n$. By the class equation, the center $Z(G)$ is nontrivial. So $Z(G)$ is normal in $G$ and abelian, hence solvable.

So either $G/Z(G)$ is a $p$-group of smaller order, or it is trivial.

> The key theorem to remember is that if $H\unlhd G$ and $H$ is solvable and $G/H$ is solvable, then $G$ is also solvable. If $|G/Z(G)|< p^n$, then by induction $G/Z(G)$ is solvable, so $G$ is solvable. Otherwise you just have $G=Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

An organized way to look at the problem is to have the following very important results in mind:

> **Proposition**. Any *nilpotent* group is solvable.

*Proof outline:* We first refer to the following relation, valid for **the descending central series** of any arbitrary group $G$:

$$[\mathrm{C}^m(G), \mathrm{C}^n(G)] \subseteq \mathrm{C}^{m+n+1}(G)$$

for arbitrary $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. On the basis of this, one can further establish by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that:

$$\mathrm{D}^n(G) \subseteq \mathrm{C}^{2^n-1}(G)$$

thanks to which matters become clear (if the $r$-th lower central subgroup is trivial, then $\mathrm{D}^r(G) \leqslant \mathrm{C}^{2^r-1}(G) \leqslant \mathrm{C}^r(G)=\{1_G\}$, bearing in mind the inequality $2^r \geqslant r+1$ valid for all $r \in \mathbb{N}$). $\Box$

> **Theorem.** Let $p \in \mathbb{N}^*$ be a prime. Any $p$-group is nilpotent.

*Proof outline:* For arbitrary group $G$ convene to denote by
$$\mathscr{S}(G)=\{H \subseteq G\ |\ H \leqslant G\}$$

the subset of all subgroups of $G$. If $m, n$ are natural numbers, then by $[m, n]$ we shall mean the interval between the two **given by the order on $\mathbb{N}$** (so for instance $[3, 5]=\{3, 4, 5\}$).

One establishes by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that given group $G$ such that $|G|=p^n$ then there exists a finite sequence $H \in \mathscr{S}^{[0, n]}$ such that:

1. $H_0=G$ and for any $k<n$ we have $H_k \geqslant H_{k+1}$ together with $|H_k:H_{k+1}|=p$ (in other words, the sequence is **strictly decreasing**).
2. For any $k<n$ we have $[G, H_k] \leqslant H_{k+1}$.

To be noted that these conditions automatically entail $H_{k} \trianglelefteq G$ (what one calls a **normal** series) and $|G:H_k|=p^k$ for any $k \leqslant n$, thus in particular $H_n=\{1_G\}$. In other words, such a sequence will clearly be a lower central series that reaches the trivial subgroup.

The inductive step is carried out by relying on the fact that if the exponent $n \geqslant 1$ (i.e. the group $G$ is not trivial) then **it will have nontrivial center**; as $\mathrm{Z}(G)$ is also a nontrivial $p$-group, we have $p|\ |\mathrm{Z}(G)|$ and hence there exists $a \in \mathrm{Z}(G)$ of order $p$. Then the group $H=\langle a \rangle$ is a normal (even central) subgroup by which you can factor out in order to apply the inductive hypothesis. $\Box$