# A group is solvable if it has only one $p$-Sylow subgroup for each $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

The problem is to prove that  a group is solvable if it has just one $p$-Sylow subgroup for each prime $p$ dividing its order.

My solution:

If$|G|=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ proof by induction on $n.$
$n=1, |G|=p_1^{\alpha_1}$ so we know that is solvable. If we assume that for $n-1$ it is true, then for $n$, $G$ has a subgroup of order $p_1^{\alpha_1}$ by Sylow's theorem, and it gonna be normal, because it is only $p_1$-Sylow subgroup. Let's call it $H_1$. By induction hypothesis $G/H_1$ is solvable, and by base of induction $H_1$ is solvable. We conclude $G$ is solvable.

Is this okay? This is my homework problem, so I want to be sure.

Comment: For $n=1$ you should add an argument, e.g., that a $p$-group is nilpotent and hence solvable. And in the end, what is your argument to say that $G$ is solvable, if $G/H_1$ and $H_1$ are? Or can you use this already? If it is homework, then I would also correct "is only $p_1$-Sylow subgroup" (an important article is missing).

Comment: For n=1, I will add an argument. In the end, I use the theorem if $H\unlhd G$ and $H$ is solvable and $G/H$ are solvable, then $G$ is also solvable. We proved that in classes. But I don't understand the problem with "only $p_1$ Sylow subgroup". What is missing? $|gH_1g^{-1}|=|H_1|=p_1^{\alpha_1}$, so $gH_1g^{-1}=H_1$

Comment: It is missing "because it is **the** only $p_1$-Sylow group", so it is normal  -see the first link of Shaun's answer below. What you wrote means" because it is just a $p_1$-Sylow subgroup".

Answer (score 1):

This follows from two theorems:

- [Why is a unique Sylow p-subgroup normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2501579/104041)
- [If all Sylow subgroups are normal then the group is solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411107/104041)