# find the factor groups of the p group - G and prove that G is solvable , where $|G|= p^a$ , p is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-groups, solvable-groups

G is a p-group -

$|G| = p^a$

p is prime

i need to find the  factor groups of G and prove that it is solvable.

what i tried -

EDITED: 
after watching the comments and investigating
I know every element of G is of order $p^i$ where $i<a $.

I try to prove that G is solvable by induction on a.

where $|G| = p^a$

if a = 1 then G is cyclic with prime order so its solvable. and the factors are 
$G/1$

if a>1 then $G/Z$ is trivial or of order less then a . if it is trivial then what does it mean? and if it is of order less then a then i know G/Z is solvable (from the induction) but how does it help me know G is solvable? 
and in this case -  what are the factor groups?

many thanks

any help will be very appreciated .

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is a $p$-group.  Does it have nontrivial subgroups?

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's theorem and its consequences?

Comment: $p$-groups are solvable: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333977/solvability-of-a-group-with-order-pn

Comment: so i know every element of G is of order $p^b$ from cauchys theorem. I understand that p-groups are solvable . but what are the factor groups?

Comment: and i also don't understand the answer to p-groups are solvable - they solve by induction on - a , where $|G| = p^a$ then they say that G/Z is trivial or of order less then a . if it is trivial then what does it mean? and if it is of order less then a then i know G/Z is solvable - how does it help me know G is solvable? many thanks

Comment: Saying $G/Z$ is trivial means $G=Z$ (so $G$ is abelian, hence solvable). Otherwise, since both $Z$ and $G/Z$ are solvable, so is $G$ (this is a basic property of solvable groups). Unfortunately, there is no hope of determining the factor groups in general.